# calling function of one class from other class in python

Tags: python, class

Suppose I have following code

```
 class ter:
    def func1()
    def func2()

 class fg:
    def gl1()
    def gl2()
      ifTrue)
        ter.func1() # func1 from class ter
```

How can I call func1 of class ter from class fg? ter.func1() is not working.

Comment: `"is not working"` is insufficient. Please post specific error messages.

Comment: This code is wrong(not Python)

Comment: I am getting this error message exceptions.TypeError: func1() takes exactly 0 argument (1 given)

Comment: @user2673943 Read my answer. Calling instance methods always require one parameter (usually called `self` in Python - just like `this` in C++, C#, etc.)

Comment: Also, your syntax has all kinds of problems.  If you're not going to declare a body of a method, you must use the `pass` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ter` is the name of the class, `ter.func1()` is the syntax for calling a [`@staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or ([`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)). Generally, you shouldn't use classes in Python just for organizing functions; instead you'd use a "free function" or module-level function.

If you actually have an *instance* of the class `ter`,  then you call the function on that name:
          # Call an "instance method" on Person object

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):    # Constructor
        self.name = name

    def sayHello(self):          # Class method (requires `self` parameter)
        print 'Hello, {0}'.format(self.name)

def main():
    p = Person('Joe')            # Instantiate `Person` class (calls constructor)
    p.sayHello()                 # Call an "instance method" on Person object
```

---

If you're *sure* you want to use static methods:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):    # Constructor
        self.name = name

    def sayHello(self):          # Class method (requires `self` parameter)
        print 'Hello, {0}'.format(self.name)

    @staticmethod
    def makePerson(name):        # Static Method (note, no `self` parameter)
        p = Person(name)
        return p

    @classmethod
    def makePerson2(cls, name):  # Class method. First parameter is class
        p = cls(name)            #    Call constructor for that class
        return p

def main():
    p2 = Person.makePerson('Joe')  # Call static "factory" method
    p2.sayHello()
```

---

Finally, even though Python doesn't have braces/brackets, it is very picky about syntax. If you're not going to declare a body of a method, you must use the [`pass` keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass):

```
def foo():
    pass        # This function does nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ter:
        def func1(self):
           print 'I am func1' 
        def func2(self):
           pass    


class fg:
        def gl1(self):
           pass
        def gl2(self):
           ter_object=ter()
           ter_object.func1()
```

This should print `I am func1`. 
The point to remember here is that you must create instances of classes unless you call static methods

Comment: @user2673943, I seriously doubt it.